# stl list in a class error C3867

Tags: c++, list, templates, visual-studio-2013, stl

I am working on a project that reads a recipe and compares it with what is in your pantry (user defined).

I have hopefully whittled down most of the problems by searching online but one is particularly annoying.

Whenever I set an iterator
list::iterator listThatIsInClass; to equal begin or end, Visual Studio Express 2013 gives me a C3867 error. There are also C2678 errors when performing logic operations, less than more than etc.

Below is one function that does not work

```
void extractData::compareInventoryRecipe()

{
    string recipIng = " ";
    string invenIng = " ";
    double recipAm = 0;
    double invenAm = 0;
    double x = 0;
    double y = 0;
    list<int>::iterator invenIterAmount;
    invenIterAmount = inventoryAmount.begin;
    list<int>::iterator recipeIterAmount;
    recipeIterAmount = recipeAmount.begin;

for (list<int>::iterator recipeIter = recipeFoodName.begin; recipeIter != recipeFoodName.end; ++recipeIter)
{
    ++recipeIterAmount;
    for (list<int>::iterator invenIter = inventoryItem.begin; invenIter != inventoryItem.end; ++invenIter)
    {
        ++invenIterAmount;
        recipIng = *recipeIter;
        invenIng = *invenIter;
        recipAm = *recipeIterAmount;
        invenAm = *invenIterAmount;
        if (recipIng.compare(invenIng) == 0)
        {
            if (invenAm < recipAm)
            {
                x += (invenAm / recipAm);
                neededAmount.push_back(invenAm - recipAm);
                neededItem.push_back(invenIng);
            }
            else
            {
                x += 1;
                recipeFoodName.remove(invenIng);
                recipeAmount.remove(invenAm);
            }
            break;
        }
        else
            continue;
    }
    y += 1;
}
setPercentOnHand((x * 100) / y);
```

}

Below is the header file. As you can see all of the lists are in protected because there was an earlier problem where functions where not accessing them in private.

```
class extractData
{
    protected:
      list<string> recipeMeasurmentType
      list<string> recipeFoodName;
      list<double> recipeAmount;

      list<string> inventoryItem;
      list<double> inventoryAmount; // do i need regular int and string as well?

      list<string> neededItem;
      list<double> neededAmount;
      list<string> measurmentLetter;
private:
    string recipeTitle;
    int choice;
    double percentOnHand;
```

I did attempt to make a Template (I am not very experienced in this) that contains the iterators. Below is the template and I have no idea what to do with it. It is a public class in the header file.

```
template <class T>
void iterators(list<T> data)
{
    typename list<T>::iterator begin();
    typename list<T>::iterator end();

    typename list<T>::const_iterator begin() const;
    typename list<T>::const_iterator end() const;
}
```

Can someone please help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: std::vector<T> should be default container unless you have reason to choose something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your class definition you have declared your lists as lists of `double`, e.g.

```
list<double> inventoryAmount;
```

Then in `extractData::compareInventoryRecipe()` you are creating an iterator for a list of `int`:

```
list<int>::iterator invenIterAmount;
invenIterAmount = inventoryAmount.begin;
```

Apart from the missing `()` on the `begin` (which causes your first error C3867), you've a type mismatch when assigning to the iterator - the lists need to be of the same type, so

```
list<double>::iterator invenIterAmount;
invenIterAmount = inventoryAmount.begin();
```

should correct the problem.

Similar problems exist for some of your other lists, e.g. `recipeAmount`.

Comment: I see. I thought that that the iterator had to be an int. I will try and update with results.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to tell us what those mysterious error codes mean and which lines they refer to. The first is

```
function call missing argument list
```

because you forgot to put `()` after various calls to `begin` and `end` functions:

```
invenIterAmount = inventoryAmount.begin();
                                       ^^
```

The second is

```
no operator defined which takes a left-hand operand of type 'type'
```

meaning that you're applying some kind of operator to a type for which that operator isn't defined. I'm guessing that comes from comparisons like `recipeIter != recipeFoodName.end`, which will be fixed when you add the missing `()`.

In general, when asking about errors, please include the exact error message, and indicate exactly which line of code caused it, with just enough code to give a test case we can use to reproduce the error. Then we won't have to guess how the error relates to your code.